# How to add dynamic objects to bindable ArrayCollection in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an `ArrayCollection` that serves as dataprovider for a `TabBar`.
Each item added must have two properties: a `label` and a `description`.

I define these items dynamically as follows:

```
[Bindable] //required to serve as data provider
private var mybar:ArrayCollection;

public function init() {
    mybar = new ArrayCollection();
    mybar.addItem({label: "Test1", description: "long test test"});
}


<s:TabBar dataProvider="{mybar}">
  <s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:ButtonBarButton label="{data.label}" /> //description might also be used here, but omitted
  </s:ItemRenderer>
</s:TabBar>
```

Problem: as the properties "label" and "description" are not set `[Bindable]`, there is the following error log:

```
warning: unable to bind to property 'label' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
warning: unable to bind to property 'description' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
```

How could I prevent this?

The warning disappears if I use `ObjectProxy`:

```
mybar.addItem(new ObjectProxy( {label: "Test1", description: "long test test"}));
```

But is that correct?

Comment: What's "ButtoBarButton"? Besides all you need to set your tabs on a spark tababr is the dataprovider. Avoid bindable as much as possible as it produce lag when overused. For simple data like this you only need to override skins and renderers.

Comment: I ment to write `ButtonBarButton` which is part of `spark.components`.

Comment: I don't think that's the way you create a tabbar to start with. Are you sure this compiles?

Comment: Absolutely (it's a legacy application that I have to maintain)

Comment: If I wrap each item in an `ObjectProxy` the warning disappears, but I don't know if that's the right way...

Comment: ok so what's the sdk target version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get rid of the warning would be using an custom class with Bindable properties.

```
[Bindable]
public class BarData
{
    public var label:String;
    public var description:String;
    public function BarData(label:String, description:String)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

and to do this to initialize it

```
public function init():void {
    mybar = new ArrayCollection();
    mybar.addItem(new BarData("Test1", "some description"));
    mybar.addItem(new BarData("Test2", "some description"));
}
```

another way as described above wrap it in an ObjectProxy:

```
public function init():void {
    mybar = new ArrayCollection();
    mybar.addItem(new ObjectProxy({label:"Test1", description:"some description"}));
    mybar.addItem(new ObjectProxy({label:"Test2", description:"some description"}));
}
```

I'm curious which SDK you're using because in my FlashBuilder, with SDK 4.7, the way you define your TabBar is leading to disappointing results. I have to do this to get it working:

```
<s:TabBar dataProvider="{mybar}">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:ButtonBarButton label="{data.label}" /> 
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:TabBar>
```

still more easy is defining it this way:

```
<s:TabBar dataProvider="{mybar}" />
```

the item renderer is not really adding extra functionality here so you could just do it this way.

Hope this helps.